# What are the possible values that can be given to `@Suppress` in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Kotlin compiler gave me the following warning:

> Warning:(399, 1) Kotlin: Expected performance impact of inlining '...' can be insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with lambda parameters

In this case I would like to suppress this warning. I don't know what value to give to `@Suppress`, however, and I can't find any documentation for what values `@Suppress` accepts.

What are the possible values that can be given to `@Suppress`, and what do they mean?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

IntelliJ gives you nice help here:

[image]

Which adds `@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")` to resolve the warning.

Some of the possible [names of the compiler diagnostics to suppress](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-suppress/) can be found in [Errors.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/diagnostics/Errors.java) and [DefaultErrorMessages.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/diagnostics/rendering/DefaultErrorMessages.java) i.e.:

```
REDUNDANT_MODIFIER, "Modifier ''{0}'' is redundant because ''{1}'' is present"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using IntelliJ, but didn't get the little "light bulb" icon earlier. Apparently it's necessary to actually place the cursor on the "inline" keyword. Seems like it would be more obvious to have this help accessible from the warning itself. Even with the IDE help, actual documentation would better.

Comment: The linked source contains the names of compiler diagnostics. Other warnings can be produced by IDE inspections. The keys aren't listed anywhere because they're simply the name of the inspection class minus the word "Inspection" at the end.

Comment: The question asked which values can be used for Suppress. They had a specific case they were trying to solve. But it would be helpful to find all of the cases. I couldn't find documentation either.

Comment: No, IntelliJ doesn't always give you nice help. The question "What are the possible values" remains unanswered.